# Add new XElements with new line in XDocument with PreserveWhitespace LoadOptions

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, whitespace

I'm trying to edit XML file saving its format:

```
<root>
    <files>
        <file>a</file>

        <file>b</file>
        <file>c</file>



        <file>d</file>
    </files>
</root>
```

So i load xml document using 
`XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);`

But when i'm trying to add new elements 
`xDoc.Root.Element("files").Add(new XElement("test","test"));
xDoc.Root.Element("files").Add(new XElement("test2","test2"));`

it adds in the same line, so output is like:

```
<root>
    <files>
        <file>a</file>

        <file>b</file>
        <file>c</file>



        <file>d</file>
    <test>test</test><test2>test2</test2></files>
</root>
```

So how can i add new elements each on new line saving initial formatting? I tried to use `XmlWriter` with `Setting.Indent = true` to save XDocument, but as i see, elements are added to the same line, when i use `xDoc.Root.Element().Add()`

Update: full part of program loading, modifying and saving document

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            string path = @".\doc.xml";    
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

            //when i debug i see in "watch" that after these commands new elements are already added in same line
            xDoc.Descendants("files").First().Add(new XElement("test", "test"));
            xDoc.Descendants("files").First().Add(new XElement("test2", "test2"));

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.IndentChars = "\t";

            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(path, settings))
            {                
                xDoc.Save(writer);
                //Here i also tried save without writer - xDoc.Save(path)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, including how you're saving with the indentation settings...

Comment: That's still not a short but complete program. It should be something we can copy, paste, compile and run, without messing around adding a `Main` method etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet done as you wished

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by your use of `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace`. This seems to trump `XmlWriterSettings.Indent` - you've basically said, "I care about this whitespace"... "Oh, now I don't."

If you remove that option, just using:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

... then it indents appropriately. If you want to preserve all the *original* whitespace but then indent just the new elements, I think you'll need to add that indentation yourself.

Comment: that's the main problem: how can i add indentation for new elements myself?

Comment: @AlexeevMikhail: You'd need to explicitly add a text node with the right number of tabs (and a line break) before each element. Do you *really* need `PreserveWhitespace`?

Comment: That's the wish of person who i making this program for, so yeah, i really need it, thank you=)

Comment: @AlexeevMikhail: Glad it helped - but I would definitely ask that person *why* they need both indentation and whitespace preservation. They're at least *somewhat* at odds. (Not entirely, but it would certainly be more convenient to only have one or the other.)

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and I could solve with the code below:

```
var newPolygon = new XElement(doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace() + "polygon");
groupElement.Add(newPolygon); 
groupElement.Add(Environment.NewLine);
```

I hope this code can help some people...